# Turning one class instance into the instance of another class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am setting up an artist community, where peers review a piece submitted. I want the administrator to turn pieces with good reviews into a product with a price, color variants, and other attributes that are not present in the original piece model, and take away attributes like reviews. Once the administrator transforms this into a product, the piece instance is destroyed. I want the administrator to do this through a form.

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150715145051) do

  create_table "prints", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.text     "description"
    t.integer  "pledge"
    t.integer  "rating"
    t.string   "category"
    t.datetime "created_at",         null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",         null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "image_file_name"
    t.string   "image_content_type"
    t.integer  "image_file_size"
    t.datetime "image_updated_at"
    t.boolean  "in_production"
  end

  create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "creator"
    t.text     "description"
    t.datetime "created_at",         null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",         null: false
    t.string   "image_file_name"
    t.string   "image_content_type"
    t.integer  "image_file_size"
    t.datetime "image_updated_at"
  end

  create_table "reviews", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "rating"
    t.text     "comment"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "subproducts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "price"
    t.integer  "quantity"
    t.string   "size"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
    t.string   "avatar_file_name"
    t.string   "avatar_content_type"
    t.integer  "avatar_file_size"
    t.datetime "avatar_updated_at"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true

  end
```

I want to transform a print into a product. Can I have an example of how this can be done through a form? I don't require the whole bulk of the code, just the gist of the idea. Thank you.

Comment: Can you ask a specific question please?

Comment: As it stands you're asking people to write a whole app for you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an unpopular question, but I found out how to do what I wanted some time later. I will post the solution for anyone that would like to do what I wanted to accomplish. 
So I wanted to make an instance of prints into a product page. I set up a control method in the print controller that created a new product instance, using the values of @print to set the product attribute values:

```
def turn_into_product
  @product = Product.new(image: @print.image, name: @print.name, \
      description: @print.description, user_id: @print.user_id, print_id: @print.id, \
   creator: @print.user.username)
respond_to do |format|
  if @product.save
    format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @product }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

I then made the connection to this method in the route file:

```
resources :prints do
  member do
    put 'flag', 'turn_into_product'
  end
end
```

Finally, I used a 'put' call link_to button on the print show page:

```
<%= link_to "Turn into Product", turn_into_product_print_path(@print), method: :put, class: "btn btn-success" %>
```

And voila, New product instance with all the attributes, including images included. At the time of the question I did not have a solid grasp of html method calls in link_to or how to use routes for put methods. I also did not know that you could create instance of another class within a foreign controller. Now that I do, the possibilities seem to have multiplied.